Completely illogical Date() values, in Swift
When I try to add a time interval to a given date at the end of some of the months, I get illogical results.
In the following example, when I add 5 hours to an 8:00PM time, in the given date, the resulted date will be the following at 1:00AM, which is expected. But if I add 6 hours instead of 5, the result will be the date after the following at 2:00AM, which completely doesn't make sense.
import SwiftUI

let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .islamic)
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.calendar = calendar
formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mma"

let components = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: 1445, month: 7, day: 29, hour: 20, minute: 0, second: 0)
let givenDate = calendar.date(from: components)!
let after_5_hours = givenDate.advanced(by: 60 * 60 * 5)
let after_6_hours = givenDate.advanced(by: 60 * 60 * 6)

formatter.string(from: givenDate)      // = "29/07/1445 20:00PM"
formatter.string(from: after_5_hours)  // = "30/07/1445 01:00AM"
formatter.string(from: after_6_hours)  // = "01/08/1445 02:00AM"

Update:
The behavior occurs while using islamic calendar. I couldn't reproduce it in gregorian calendar

Is the behavior different for different years?

Assalaam alykum! I have not use the .islamic calendar in iOS but I'm thinking, could it be that the FORMATTER also has to be set correctly, somehow ?

Did you try the other formats of that command, like .date(byAdding: .day, value: ..etc It may lead to some finding.

Exactly, use the same calendar instance for adding. calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 5, to: givenDate)!

@ScottHunter the behavior is the same for some months in some years. I'm getting this results randomly

@Fattie the formatter is global and constant. It doesn't make sense to change it for every date

@JoakimDanielson I will try calendar.date(byAdding...)

"Random" is not necessarily the same as "a pattern I don't see".  Which months/years do you see this happen with?

@JoakimDanielson the following code didn't work. still getting the same unexpected results.
calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 5, to: givenDate)

@ScottHunter this behavior happens for 29/7/1445 and 29/12/1445

Is the behavior different for different years?

This looks like daylight savings time. What's your time zone?

@Mohammed - cheers, what i meant is you may have to set something (once) in formatter but I think it's just daylight savings time, as RobNapier menionts

@ScottHunter The behavior appears in other years as well, like 29/4/1444

@RobNapier my time zone is "Asia/Kuwait". there is no daylight savings

@Fattie There is no daylight savings in the region I'm testing (Asia/Kuwait)

Using Calendar(identifier: .islamicCivil) fixes the problem.
